# Upsample and Interpolate a NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have an array, something like:

```
array = np.arange(0,4,1).reshape(2,2)

> [[0 1
    2 3]]
```

I want to both upsample this array as well as interpolate the resulting values. I know that a good way to upsample an array is by using:

```
array = eratemp[0].repeat(2, axis = 0).repeat(2, axis = 1)
[[0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [2 2 3 3]
 [2 2 3 3]]
```

but I cannot figure out a way to interpolate the values to remove the 'blocky' nature between each 2x2 section of the array.

I want something like this:

```
[[0 0.4 1 1.1]
 [1 0.8 1 2.1]
 [2 2.3 3 3.1]
 [2.1 2.3 3.1 3.2]]
```

Something like this (NOTE: these will not be the exact numbers). I understand that it may not be possible to interpolate this particular 2D grid, but using the first grid in my answer, an interpolation should be possible during the upsampling process as you are increasing the number of pixels, and can therefore 'fill in the gaps'.

I am not too fussed on the type of interpolation, providing the final output is a smoothed surface! I have tried to use the scipy.interp2d method but to no avail, would be grateful if someone could share their wisdom!

Comment: Are you wanting to do a two-dimensional interpolation?  I do not see how this would work.  As you as you interpolate one axis you would break the interpolation of the other.  Right?

Comment: “you get the idea!” — sorry, I don’t quite get it. Could you fill out the rest of the 4x4 array that you’re expecting?

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I have filled in the rest of the grid to give some idea of my desired result. I understand that interpolating the second 2D grid in my answer may be problematic, but there must be a way to interpolate the the first grid whilst the upsampling process is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use SciPy `interp2d` for the interpolation, you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html).

I've modified the example from the documentation a bit:

```
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.array(range(2))
y = np.array(range(2))
a = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, a, kind='linear')

xnew = np.linspace(0, 2, 4)
ynew = np.linspace(0, 2, 4)
znew = f(xnew, ynew)
```

If you print `znew` it should look like this:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.66666667,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.33333333,  2.        ,  2.33333333,  2.33333333],
       [ 2.        ,  2.66666667,  3.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 2.        ,  2.66666667,  3.        ,  3.        ]])
```

Comment: +1 Thankyou! Good use of an existing function to do both my upsampling and interpolation steps in one go!

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html):

```
array = np.arange(0,4,1).reshape(2,2)
from skimage.transform import resize
out = scipy.misc.imresize(array, 2.0)
```

The `2.0` indicates that I want the output to be twice the dimensions of the input. You could alternatively supply an `int` or a `tuple` to specify a percentage of the original dimensions or just the new dimensions themselves.

This is very easy to use, but there is an extra step because `imresize` rescales everything so that your max value becomes 255 and your min becomes 0. (And it changes the datatype to `np.unit8`.) You may need to do something like:

```
out = out.astype(array.dtype) / 255 * (np.max(array) - np.min(array)) + np.min(array)
```

Let's look at the **output**:

```
>>> out.round(2)
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.75, 1.  ],
       [0.51, 0.75, 1.26, 1.51],
       [1.51, 1.75, 2.26, 2.51],
       [2.  , 2.25, 2.75, 3.  ]])
```

`imresize` comes with a deprecation warning and a substitute, though:

> DeprecationWarning: `imresize` is deprecated! `imresize` is deprecated
>   in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use
>   `skimage.transform.resize` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Form resample method in SciPy. Signal you can up-sample your 2d array sequentially in one axis and then the other axis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).