# Nearest Upsampling using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

Supose i have,

```
x = [[1 ,2],
     [3 ,4]]
```

and id like to have,

```
y = [[1 ,1 ,2 ,2],
     [1 ,1 ,2 ,2],
     [3 ,3 ,4 ,4],
     [3 ,3 ,4 ,4]]
```

I already did it using repeat but my question is, if theres a way in pure numpy which is faster and vectorized.

My second question is, how could you efficiently downsaple from y back to x?

thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upsample and Interpolate a NumPy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879104/upsample-and-interpolate-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Or perhaps: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html

Comment: not really,  becuase i need it in numpy but as i said in a faster way than with .repeat

Comment: `repeat` is fast and vectorized :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the output shape, you can do this operation just by changing the metadata

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (4,2,2), (8,0,0))
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [4, 4]]])
```

further, `np.block` will give the desired output shape (by copying)

```
x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (4,2,2), (8,0,0))
np.block([[x[0], x[1]], 
          [x[2], x[3]]])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

The `np.block` can also be simulated by using `transpose` and `reshape`:

```
x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (1,2,2,2,2), (32,16,0,8,0))
x.reshape(4,4) # copy!
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Although, this will copy memory just like `np.block`. You can verify this trying to set the shape directly by `x.shape = (4,4)`:

```
AttributeError: Incompatible shape for in-place modification. Use `.reshape()` to make a copy with the desired shape.
```

In the same fashion the output can be down-sampled just by changing the shape and strides:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (2,2), (8*8,8*2))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Notice that this is done without any copying. The reason i multiply with `8` is that it is the size in bytes of a 64 bit integer.

**Generalizable solution**

```
def upsample(x, k):
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (np.prod(x.shape), k, k), (x.dtype.itemsize, 0, 0))
```

Comment: when i run the first snippet somehow my output is: array([[[        1,         1],
        [        1,         1]],

       [[        3,         3],
        [        3,         3]],

       [[        1,         1],
        [        1,         1]],

       [[462730709, 462730709],
        [462730709, 462730709]]])

Comment: This version is not generalized for any input. But the principle is the same, I will edit my answer with a solution that will work for any array.

Comment: thanks! but the output was produced using x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

Comment: make sure that the dtype for x is 64 bit integer. Try running ```x = x.astype(np.int64)``` first

Comment: I edited my answer with a generalizable solution of the first code snippet. It should work with any dtype and positive up-sampling factor. This should give you enough information to make the other methods also work for any array.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`np.kron()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) the kronecker product:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.kron(x,np.ones((2,2))   # np.ones((n,n)) where n indicate the number of repetition.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one: Uses simple broadcasted multiplication followed by transpose and reshape operations.

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
m, n = x.shape
k = 2 # upsampling factor

tmp = x.reshape(-1, 1, 1) * np.ones((1, k, k))
y = tmp.reshape(m, n, k, k).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(m*k, n*k)
print(y)
```

```
array([[1., 1., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 4., 4.],
       [3., 3., 4., 4.]])
```

To get `x` back from `y`, simply reverse the reshape and transpose operations and do a maxpool kind of operation along the last two axes to get back the original *m x n* shaped array:

```
x = y.reshape(m, n, k, k).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).max(axis = (2, 3))
```

This method works for any array of shape *m x n* and upsampling factor *k*.

Comment: Great! But I didn't benchmark it against repeat. Is it comparable in terms of speed?

Comment: its slower on cpu but on gpu it completely outperforms repeat